# How to print all possible strings of x-length from a text. Preverably in BASH

Tags: bash

I am trying to get all possible strings from a text using bash.

I have been looking for quite a while and find it hard to find the right search terms to get a proper answer to the problem.
I tried to do it with grep:
    `echo "123456789" | grep -o '..\{0,1\}'
    echo "123456789" | grep -E -o '..{0,1}'
    echo "123456789" | grep -o -P '..{0,1}'
    echo "1234567890" | grep -o ".."`

And this gives always the output:

```
12
34
56
78
90
```

The output I want to generate is:

```
# for x=2
12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
90

# for x=3
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
890
```

I think there is a simple solution to this problem.
In my case the text is much larger and also the output is supposed to contain more characters per line.
A solution in bash would be much appreciated because my programming skills a nearly non exsistent.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With perl

```
echo "1234567890" |  perl -lne 'while(/.{2}/){print $&;s/.//}'
12
23
34
45
56
67
78
89
90
```

Replace two with whatever length you want.

Answer (score 0):

OP needs to make this adaptable to any length. It can be two, or 4 or 666. This is not covered on other responses.

```
echo "1234567890"  | awk '
 { limit=split($1,mystring,"");  
   perm_length = 4;
 for ( i=1; i < limit ; i++){ 
    for ( j=0 ; (j < perm_length) && (i < limit) ; j++) {
        printf  mystring[i]
        if ( (j +1) < perm_length )
            i++     
    }
    printf "\n"
 } 
 }'
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Variation on @Roman's `awk` solution to support a variable length output string:

```
echo "1234567890" |
awk -v x=3 '{ len=split($0,a,"")
              for (i=1; i <= (len-x+1) ; i++)
                  { for (y=i ; y < (i+x) ; y++)
                        printf a[y]
                    printf "\n"
                  }
            }'

123
234
345
456
567
678
789
890
```

- `x=3` : print 3-character strings; modify accordingly
- `for (i=1 ...)` : loop through array elements, ignoring last `x` values
- `for (y=i ...)` : loop through next `x` array elements starting at position `i` ...
- `printf a[y]` : print array element (ie, character); remain on current line
- `printf "\n"` : after printing `x` characters, print a new line character

And the one-liner:

```
echo "1234567890" | awk -v x=3 '{ len=split($0,a,""); for(i=1;i<=(len-x+1);i++) { for(y=i;y<(i+x);y++) printf a[y] ; printf "\n" }
```

NOTE: I can delete this if/when @Roman updates his answer (ie, not trying to steal @Roman's thunder) ... though @James' answer is a bit more to the point

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
$ echo 1234567890 | \
  awk -F '' -v n=3 '{for(i=1;i<=(NF-n+1);i++)print substr($0,i,n)}'
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
890
```

Using GNU awk's `-F ''` for no reason particular. You could remove it and replace the `NF` in the `for` loop with `length($0)`.